# validation conrtol give's problem while clicked on button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, validation

i am developing a site in asp.net as front-end
In my Form, 
i have a 3 text-box with validation control on it eg: requiredFieldValidator 
with joinnow button. and search button  with 2 textbox with no validation control on it

when i click on search button it is asking me to fill the three text box for validation and it is not redirected to other page

i need that when i click on search button my form should redirect

Comment: how ??? new to this site

Comment: @user, on questions that you have asked before click the checkbox next to the answer that you liked the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
solution for it is 

set the property of the search button as below 

CausesValidation="False"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `ValidationGroup` properties on your textbox that has the validation and the joinnow button to the same thing.  When you click the button it will validate controls in its group, and thus not validate from the search button (which is in a different validation group implicitly)